# How to send data from PHP script running on server to Standalone application in a Remote IP

Tags: java, php, sockets

> I want to send some information from a hosted Server to a Standalone application in my laptop (Remote Host NOT localhost). I have a PHP script running at server which collects information from Query String and through Socket Programming it sends to IP of my laptop and a port to which a Java program (executed in my laptop) is listening.
>
> Neither the socket gets created/connected at Server end nor the Message gets received at Client end.
>
> Could anyone please point out the mistake in the below codes or suggest any other better approach to implement this task.
>
> > *URL of PHP page on Server*: http://remoteinformer.hostoi.com/HandleRequest.php?name=karthik&number=9900882867

***PHP script at Server Side***

```
<?php
$name=$_GET["name"];
$number=$_GET["number"];
$message="Name:$name, Number:$number";
$host    = "101.63.71.24";
$port    = 1111;

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Couldn't create socket<br>");
echo "Socket created <br>";
 
//Connect socket to remote server
socket_connect($sock , $host , $port) or die("Could not connect<br>");
echo "Connection established <br>";
 
//Send the message to the server
socket_send ( $sock , $message , strlen($message) , 0) or die("Could not send data<br>");
echo "Message sent successfully <br>";
  
socket_close($sock);  
?>
```

***Java Program at Client Side (IP: 101.63.71.24)***

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPClient {

    public TCPClient() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception{
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(1111);
        System.out.println("Waiting for server");
        Socket soc=ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Message received");
    }

}
```

***Output of Java Program listening to Port:1111 of client for message from Server***

[Java Program listening to Port:1111 for message from Server http://remoteinformer.hostoi.com/waiting_error.jpg](http://remoteinformer.hostoi.com/waiting_error.jpg)

Comment: Dont use real values like `IP` on your questions

Comment: In this case, your server is the java program, the client is the PHP-Host. Which error is returned by `socket_connect`, if you check with `socket_last_error` and `socket_str_error`? Just a wild guess: Maybe it's simply the firewall on your local host blocking incoming connections on port 1111?